# How do I store results of a loop into one (1) dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, google-sheets

I have some python code which runs a loop across different "databases" and stores each database separately. How do I save the content from he ten (10) loops into one daataframe that I can save / export or push to Google Sheets?

Here's a preview of my code below:

```
USERNAME = 'email'
PASSWORD = 'password'
DATABASES = [ 'DB1', 'DB2', 'DB3', 'DB4', 'DB5', 'DB6', 'DB7', 'DB8', 'DB9', 'DB10' ]

def get_dataframe(db):
    client = my.API(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, database=db)
    client.authenticate()

    device_status = client.get("DeviceStatusInfo")
    device_serial = client.get("Device")


    df = pandas.DataFrame(device_serial)
    ids = list(df['id'])
    sn = list(df['serialNumber'])
    nm = list(df['name'])
    cm = list(df['comment'])
    dt = list(df['deviceType'])

    di = pandas.DataFrame(device_status)
    device_ids = di['device']

    dev_id = []
    for device_id in device_ids:
        dev_id.append(device_id['id'])

    di['id'] = pandas.Series(dev_id)

    d = {
        'id':ids,
        'serialNumber':sn,
        'name':nm,
        'comment':cm,
        'deviceType':dt
    }


    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(d)
    dfo = pandas.merge(di, df2, on='id')

    print(dfo)

    return dfo
```

In addition, here's the loop below:

```
def main():

    for db in DATABASES:
        df = get_dataframe(db)

        gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
        sh = gc.open_by_key('1vToay2IueDcV0gzu6MCehcMUU6Frea1fa3lqjpoKdSs')
        worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

        dfo = pandas.DataFrame(df)
        set_with_dataframe(worksheet, dfo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help from anyone would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure i understood your question completely and I can't add a comment still but have you tried creating an empty data frame outside of the loop and then using concat, for example:

```
def main():
final_df=pandasd.DataFrame(columns=['your column names'])
for db in DATABASES:
    df = get_dataframe(db)
    final_df=pandas.concat([df,final_df])

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1vToay2IueDcV0gzu6MCehcMUU6Frea1fa3lqjpoKdSs')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
set_with_dataframe(worksheet, final_df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

P.S: this method is slow and a better way would be always to store your databases as numpy arrays and only creating the data frame after the loops ,as working with pandas data frame is slow.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using the following concat method:

def main():
    dfo = pd.concat([get_dataframe(db) for db in DATABASES])

    gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
    sh = gc.open_by_key('1vToay2IueDcV0gzu6MCehcMUU6Frea1fa3lqjpoKdSs')
    worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

    set_with_dataframe(worksheet, dfo)